# Meaning of "so" in the following context

Tags: meaning

I need help with the meaning of "so" in the following context. Could you paraphrase it?
Also, what is the grammar applied here?

> These ideas may be developed by children absorbing ideas through the
>   popular media. Sometimes this information may be erroneous. It seems
>   schools may not be providing an opportunity for children to re-express
>   their ideas and **so have them** tested and refined by teachers and
>   their peers.

Much appreciated.

Comment: *and so*: "3. And then; as the next step. ‘and so to the final’" https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/so

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Good question. However, we need to show some background effort done before posting a question. Please read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Kris. I think your answer might be the one that makes the most sense to me. And I will refer to the rules in my future posts.

Comment: thereby / by doing this

Answer (score 2):

The passage is saying that children get ideas from outside the classroom – from the popular media. But not all this information is correct. Some schools don't allow children to express these ideas in the classroom. The result is that false ideas are not challenged or corrected.

The grammatical purpose of **so** is a [conjunction](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/so)

> **so**
>   CONJUNCTION
>
> **2** (**so that**) With the aim that; in order that.
>   *they whisper to each other so that no one else can hear*

The last sentence

> It seems schools may not be providing an opportunity for children to re-express their ideas and so have them tested and refined by teachers and their peers.

can be broken down like this

> It seems – **it is believed [that]**
>   schools may not be providing an opportunity for – **schools don't allow**
>   children to re-express their ideas – **children to talk freely**
>   and so – ***with the aim***
>   have them tested and refined – **of [those ideas] being corrected**
>   by teachers and their peers. – **by the teachers and other children.**

Comment: It's the 'and so = with the aim' one

Comment: @marcellothearcane I trimmed it down to that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @WeatherVane. Very helpful.

Comment: @learningc you are welcome. On this site we give thanks by voting: usually you can **accept** the answer you think is best.

Comment: See also: my comment at OP above.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems schools may not be providing an opportunity for children to re-express their ideas and so have them tested and refined by teachers and their peers.

Here, 'so' is used as a short form of 'in doing so'.